Нужны ли запятые в предложении с деепричастным оборотом ниже?
За осуществление торговой деятельности(?) не имея на это права(?) предусмотрена административная ответственность.

 ИЗ ОТВЕТА НА ВОПРОС
 Здесь не деепричастный оборот, а производный 
 предлог "не имея". Запятая не нужна.

Но так ли это? Может быть, пора обсудить тему "Чем производные предлоги на основе деепричастий отличаются от деепричастий?"
Информация о производных предлогах на основе деепричастий

ПАС § 73.

Обороты со словами смотря по, начиная с, потерявшими свое глагольное значение и перешедшими в предлоги и предложные сочетания, не обособляются: Будем действовать смотря по обстоятельствам (ср.: по обстоятельствам); Начиная со вторника погода резко изменилась (ср.: Со вторника погода резко изменилась). Если же эти обороты имеют значение уточнения или присоединения, то они обособляются: Будем действовать умело и быстро, смотря по обстоятельствам; На прошлой неделе, начиная со вторника, погода резко изменилась.
Оборот со словами исходя из может иметь два значения: если действие, обозначаемое им, соотносится с действующим лицом, он обособляется; при отсутствии такой связи — не обособляется.

Ответы на mail.ru Напишите все известные вам предлоги, производные от деепричастий.

Благодаря заботам, несмотря на болезнь, спустя неделю, невзирая на препятствия, исходя из написанного
Включая, погодя, не доходя, не считая, невзирая на, несмотря на, исходя из, начиная с, спустя.

Ответы Справочной службы

№ 317697.
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли употреблен деепричастный оборот в следующем предложении: "Читая приведённые ниже примеры, важно помнить, что..."?
Ответ.
Да, деепричастный оборот здесь употреблен правильно.
Употребление ДЕЕПРИЧАСТНОГО ОБОРОТА, не выражающего действия подлежащего, возможно в безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например: Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, НЕ ИМЕЯ в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха. Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно, например: *Уезжая из родного города, мне стало грустно;
*Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что она нуждается в серьезной доработке.

Запятые нужны, однако предложение лучше перестроить. За осуществление торговой деятельности без соответствующего права предусмотрена административная ответственность.

Редактирование корректное, но  предложение с деепричастным оборотом однозначно не подойдет, так как оборот должен относиться к производителю действия, а здесь пассивная конструкция.

Здесь не деепричастный оборот, а производный предлог "не имея". Запятая не нужна. Сравните с аналогичными конструкциями с обычными предлогами

За осуществление торговой деятельности без права на это
предусмотрена административная ответственность


За осуществление торговой деятельности при отсутствии права на это
предусмотрена административная ответственность

итд
